# verbose_name does not working in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm make a project using django

when i create user models using `AbstractUser`, I insert `verbose_name` in `class META`

here is my code

**In `projectname/users/models/user.py`**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):

    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name = 'UserPhoneNumber',
        )

    class META:
        verbose_name = '유저'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

I want see '유저' in User table in admin page
but admin page show me `Users`,,, not `유저`
(but `phone's verbose_name` has no problem)

I think it maybe admin.py error

so I check my mistake in admin.py

**In `users/admin/users.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from users.models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = admin.ModelAdmin.list_display + (
            'phone',
            'email',
            )
```

but I think it has no problem;;

please some body help me

Comment: It should be `class Meta`, not `class META`.

Comment: @solarissmoke oh my god... thank you! I solved my problem.... It is my shy mistake thak you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code statement as Meta:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = u'유저'
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

Comment: my mistake is `META` I must use `class Meta` but `u'유저'` is working too thank you @Rajesh

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'유저'
```

Comment: ummm... I try change the code using your advice but it doesn't working...